# What dependency am I missing?

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to analyze https://github.com/mono/monodevelop with Sonar but I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Caused by: com.sonar.vbnet.plugin.K has unsatisfied dependency 'class com
.sonar.vbnet.plugin.E' for constructor 'public com.sonar.vbnet.plugin.K(com.sona
r.vbnet.plugin.E)' from org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer@3834a1c8:237<[Imm
utable]:org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer@604ee1f1:20<[Immutable]:org.picoc
ontainer.DefaultPicoContainer@20eb607d:111<|
```

I have found nothing about it on the internet and I have no idea about how to further investigate this, any hint?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: What are your versions of SonarQube and the VB.NET plugin?

Comment: SonarQube 4.2 & Vb.net 1.1 & SonarRunner 2.3. Sorry for the late response :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 1.1 of the VB.NET plugin is not compatible with SonarQube 4.2. See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Plugin+version+matrix.

Comment: Thanks, i did not see that coming. Right now i am onnvacations but as soon as i get back to work i'll investigate how could this happen to me.

Comment: Just uninstalling the plugin did work for me, I think I installed that plugin manually instead of through the update system, because now i do not see it as available for install.